# What is the lifecycle of an installed Progressive Web App on Android?

Tags: android, progressive-web-apps

I have a strong Android background but I have recently developed a PWA that can be installed to a users device. I have noticed that when the app starts for the first time, the splash screen shows and then the app displays it's first page which is great. Now, if the app has been backgrounded for a while and I relaunch the app, it sometimes appears to display a white screen for a few seconds then the app kind of flickers and some aspects of the page reload, creating a jarring experience.

I am familiar with how lifecycles work in Android, saveInstanceState and all that jazz, but what is actually happening here with a PWA is backgrounded? I am unable to debug what is happening because it takes a long time to reproduce and the debugger needs to be attached before launching the app.

Are there any documents describing exactly what is happening with the lifecycle of an installed PWA and how to gracefully restore it when it has been backgrounded or background-killed?

Answer (score 1):

You may look into this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/codelabs/your-first-pwapp/#use_service_workers_to_pre-cache_the_app_shell). *"Progressive Web Apps have to be fast, and installable, which means that they work online, offline, and on intermittent, slow connections. To achieve this, we need to cache our app shell using service worker, so that it's always available quickly and reliably."* A service worker has a [lifecycle](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/service-workers#the_service_worker_life_cycle) that is completely separate from your web page. Based from this [article](https://8thlight.com/blog/rabea-gleissner/2016/09/14/intro-to-progressive-web-apps.html), a service worker lifecycle usually has three stages:

- The **install stage**, during which it is common to cache assets like stylesheets, client-side JavaScript, and so on.
- When the install stage was successful, the **activation step** happens, during which any obsolete caches are deleted.
- Then, the service worker is **idle** until it needs to deal with a request from the client code.

You may read the article for more information. Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't answer the question. I knew about these things. What I am asking about is what happens to a PWA when it has been background killed by the OS, and then the user tries to multitask back to the app. It does not appear to follow this same lifecycle... the splash screen doesn't show and the app tries to restore it's previous state, but the details of how this restore takes place appears to be hidden.

Comment: @Mr_E It's almost 2020, and I am looking for the same answer. For all platforms actually, not just Android. Have you found information you could share?

Comment: Now, it's 2023, and I'm still looking for the Lifecycle of a PWA. Any information?